# Coq unable to unify -- how to change hypothesis?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Coq beginner here.

I have the following silly theorems:

```
  Theorem plus_same : forall a b c : nat,
      a+b=a+c -> b=c.
  Proof. Admitted.

  Theorem advanced_commutivity:
    forall x y z w : nat, x + y + (z+w) = x + z + (y + w).
  Proof.
    intros x y z w.
    apply (plus_same x (y + (z+w)) (z + (y + w))).
```

However, when I try to run the `apply` line, I get an error:

```
Unable to unify "y + (z + w) = z + (y + w)" with
 "x + y + (z + w) = x + z + (y + w)".
```

Do I need to change my hypothesis here? How can I apply `plus_same` here to the arguments in `advanced_commutivity` proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misreading your goal: `x + y + (z + w)` stands for `(x + y) + (z + w)`, because `+` is registered as left-associative, which is different from `x + (y + (z + w))`.

So in order to apply your lemma, you should first reassociate your `+` by rewriting with another `Lemma plus_assoc : forall x y z, x + y + z = x + (y + z).`

Comment: True, but there is another problem. The `plus_same` theorem says that if you have `x + ...`, then you can get rid of the `x`. In this case you want to end up with `x + ...`, so actually you need the oposite implication of `plus_same`:
`Theorem same_plus (a b c : nat) : b = c -> a + b = a + c.`